# Add text to a recognized image via ARKIT

Tags: swift, arkit

Right now I have a simple image detection, with an overlay of a SCNPlane.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {

    let node = SCNNode()

    if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {

        let plane = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)

        plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)
        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)

        planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

        node.addChildNode(planeNode)
    }

    return node

}
```

Instead of the image overlay, I want to display a simple text on the right side of the recognized image.

I already tried:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {

    let node = SCNNode()

        let text = SCNText(string: "testtext", extrusionDepth: 1)
        let material = SCNMaterial()

        material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
        text.materials = [material]

        let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: text)


        node.addChildNode(textNode)

    return node

}
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the result of the code you've tried? Is the text node added to the scene or what?

Comment: No errors / warnings, but nothing happened. No text or anything

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Maybe the problem is the way you're adding the anchor?